# Magento 2.3 is extremely slow?

Tags: magento2, performance, server-setup, apache, pagespeed

We are using magneto 2.3 as well as using Control S server but our website very slow response time apex 30 seconds.
we have same website upload on AWS server its take 10 second maximum. 
we have already perform all setting like merge css and magnify css as well as js file.

I assume when requests on server its take 30 second.Please let me know how can improve the speed.

Comment: You have already clear that your  issue at Server where Aws did the good response time

Comment: try to run profiler

Comment: As far as i can see you have answered your own question that the server it is sat on is not powerful enough to handle the instance of magento i would recommend keeping it on aws or try a magestack instance

Comment: Dava Gordan, Agree with your point. It is server issue not an application issue.

Comment: Please let me know which configuration required for this or which command can perform on live server

Answer (score 0):

Following things to consider:

1. Check if memory is sufficient like 4GB atleast.
2. On js/css minification.
3. Enable cache(You can use Varnish/Redis).
4. Set production mode.
5. If it still not helping then run profiler and check which class is responsible and optimize accordingly.
6. Avoid using around plugin.
7. Use CDN.
8. Use Elastic search.

Comment: how exactly this copy-paste answer helps with his speed issues??? why he needs ELK??? what is around plugin?

Comment: We are not using around function in magento

Answer (score 0):

Code execution has two parts:
1. Server time and
2. HTML related downloading time( css, JS, Media, third party fonts and scripts etc ).

So first make sure whats your TTFB.

Using GtMatrix or a similar speed test tool you will get that.
If its high then check cache and sql query log and identify blocks or modules responsible for this issue.
If its okay then check html related issues.

Html related :
1. Image size( responsive images recommended )
2. CDN recommended to avoid too much of latency.
3. Third party fonts and scripts.
4. Head should not have lots of js and third party request.

If you post TTFB and other details regarding speed performance report we will be able to comment further.